# Run Detections with Darknet and YOLOv3 with coco dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to run the YOLOv3 objection algorithm in their dataset(coco file).
I suddenly faced an error that's been taken.

**Download Pretariained YOLOv3 weights,**

```
!wget https://pjredddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights
```

**function to show after prediction,**

```
def imshow(path):
  import cv2
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  %matplotlib inline

  image = cv2.imread(path)
  height, width=image.shape[:2]
  resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (3*width, 3*height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
  
  fig = plt.gfc()
  fig.set_size_inches(18,10)
  plt.axis("off")
  plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(resized_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
  plt.show()
```

**Run Detections with Darknet and YOLOv3,**

```
!./darknet detect <path to config> <path to weights> <path to image>
```

**Now, The error is,**

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `./darknet detect <path to config> <path to weights> <path to image>'
```

**Note:** `!./darknet detect <path to config> <path to weights> <path to image>` in this code I enter `<>` token from keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this `<>` in command, you have to write actual paths like this.

```
./darknet detect ./data/yolov3.cfg ./data/yolov3.weights ./test/img.bmp
```